# swing autocomplete text field / drop down

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete

We need an autocomplete component for swing, the problem with the one in jdesktop/SwingX is that we have to use a combo box and after each key stroke it simply scrolls down to the nearest match but the combo still holds the 25.000 elements. It doesn't show the 4 or 5 that are the closest match together because they can be in different places of the list. We don't want to display a list with the 25000 either...

Is there anything similar to the JSF autocomplete or the one in google main page? What we need is a component which asks our interface something like

public List getOptions(String typedSoFar) {
  //here we return the 5 matching ones according to our criteria and simply offers the //user those five
}

Answer (score 5):

A really easy way to do this is to use the GlazedList implementation of auto-completion.  It's very easy to get up and running.  You can find it here:

http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/

You can install the auto-complete on a JComboBox with only one line of Glazed code, like this:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
Object[] elements = new Object[] {"Cat", "Dog", "Lion", "Mouse"};
AutoCompleteSupport.install(comboBox, GlazedLists.eventListOf(elements));
```

Answer (score 1):

GlazedList Not very good, also SwingX support Auto-Complete and easier than "GlazedList".
 you only writing:

```
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(yourComboBox);
```

Comment: Things that would make this answer more helpful: What's not good about GlazedList?  Link to SwingX project and its AutoCompleteDecorator?  Where do you supply the autocomplete word-list?

Answer (score 0):

swingX is the best answer.

```
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(textComplete, strings, true);
```

where `textComplete` is the textbox, `strings` is the jList with the suggestion dictionary and last value is whether to restrict the contents of the text field to the dictionary or not.

Answer (score -2):

I have not used SwingX and know nothing about their implementation. The best idea would probably be to extend the SwingX Autocomplete class. Instead of using the Autocomplete class directly, create a proprietary class extendig the Autocomplete class and override the getOptions() method:

```
class OurOwnAutocomplete extending swingx.*.*.autocomplete {

    private List getOptions(String typedSoFar) { // 

    // logic 

   }
```

Comment: There is no such method getOptions in the Autocomplete from swingX